# Kubernetes Ingress-Controllers "fighting" over Address in Ingress

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, kubernetes-ingress, ingress-nginx

## Infrastructure Background:

I have 4 nodes in my Kubernetes (K3s) cluster.

```
k3s-server location=home   (VM) maily used for etcd replication 
k3s-agent  location=home   (VM) runs most pods
mercury    location=home   (RPI4) backup for important pods
moon       location=cloud  (Cloud VM) runs certain workloads in a public cloud
```

I am running 2 different instances of the `ingress-nginx` helm chart in two namespaces. One to exposes local services at my home when `ingressClassName=nginx` using `loadBalancerIP: 192.168.113.230` running in the `nginx-ingres-home` namespace. The cloud controller uses `ingressClassName=nginx-cloud` with `loadBalancerIP: 91.x.x.x` and runs inside the `nginx-ingress-cloud` namespace. (Values for the Helm charts & example Ingress below)

## The Problem

I now have multiple Ingresses defined, which are using the different classes. However using `kubectl get ingress -A` provides the following output.

```
NAMESPACE              NAME                   CLASS         HOSTS                        ADDRESS           PORTS     AGE
kubernetes-dashboard   kubernetes-dashboard   nginx         k3s.local.example.com        192.168.113.230   80, 443   4d3h
longhorn-system        longhorn-ingress       nginx         longhorn.local.example.com   192.168.113.230   80, 443   10d
mailu                  mailu                  nginx-cloud   mail.example.com             192.168.113.230   80, 443   2d23h
pihole                 pihole                 nginx         dns.local.example.com        192.168.113.230   80, 443   10d
ubiquiti               unifi-web-interface     nginx         unifi.local.example.com       192.168.113.230   80, 443   24h
```

You can see that regardless of the `ingressClassName` set in the Ingress, the addresses are always the ones from one of the ingress-controllers. The addresses are switching periodically. The logs of `nginx-ingress-home` show, that the controller permanently updates the addresses of the Ingresses (1m interval):

```
I0510 19:46:12.087815       7 status.go:300] "updating Ingress status" namespace="pihole" ingress="pihole" currentValue=[{IP:91.x.x.x Hostname: Ports:[]}] newValue=[{IP:192.168.113.230 Hostname: Ports:[]}]
I0510 19:46:12.087857       7 status.go:300] "updating Ingress status" namespace="ubiquiti" ingress="unifi-web-interface" currentValue=[{IP:91.x.x.x Hostname: Ports:[]}] newValue=[{IP:192.168.113.230 Hostname: Ports:[]}]
I0510 19:46:12.088485       7 status.go:300] "updating Ingress status" namespace="mailu" ingress="mailu" currentValue=[{IP:91.x.x.x Hostname: Ports:[]}] newValue=[{IP:192.168.113.230 Hostname: Ports:[]}]
I0510 19:46:12.088782       7 status.go:300] "updating Ingress status" namespace="longhorn-system" ingress="longhorn-ingress" currentValue=[{IP:91.x.x.x Hostname: Ports:[]}] newValue=[{IP:192.168.113.230 Hostname: Ports:[]}]
I0510 19:46:12.090051       7 status.go:300] "updating Ingress status" namespace="kubernetes-dashboard" ingress="kubernetes-dashboard" currentValue=[{IP:91.x.x.x Hostname: Ports:[]}] newValue=[{IP:192.168.113.230 Hostname: Ports:[]}]
```

Of course the `nginx-ingress-cloud` does the same thing, just replacing `192.168.113.230` with `91.x.x.x`.

Does somebody know, how to stop them from "taking owernship" of all Ingresses and only updating the ones with the same IngressClass assigned?

#### Configs

##### Values of nginx-ingress-home

```
controller:
  ingressClass: "nginx"
  ingressClassResource:
    name: nginx
    enabled: yes
    default: yes
  service:
    type: "LoadBalancer"
    loadBalancerIP: 192.168.113.230
  nodeSelector:
    location: home
  tolerations: #Allow running on backup nodes
    - key: "backup"
      operator: "Equal"
      value: "true"
      effect: "NoSchedule"
  affinity: #Prefer running on nodes labled type=power
    nodeAffinity:
      preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        - weight: 1
          preference:
            matchExpressions:
              - key: type
                operator: In
                values:
                  - power
```

##### Values of nginx-ingress-cloud

```
controller:
  ingressClass: "nginx-cloud"
  ingressClassResource:
    name: nginx-cloud
    enabled: yes
    default: no
  service:
    type: "LoadBalancer"
    loadBalancerIP: 91.x.x.x
  nodeSelector:
    location: cloud
```

##### Example home Ingress: Pihole

```
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - k3s.local.example.com
      secretName: kubernetes-dashboard-tls
  rules:
    - host: k3s.local.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              service:
                name: kubernetes-dashboard
                port:
                  number: 443

            path: /
            pathType: Prefix
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ingress constantly changing ip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72998025/ingress-constantly-changing-ip)

Comment: Sadly no, but it gave me clues, and I now found my awnser. Will post awnser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of a comment from [Blender Fox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76222260/kubernetes-ingress-controllers-fighting-over-address-in-ingress#comment134416606_76222260) I was able to figure out the solution.

The `IngressClass` objects have the property `spec.controller`, which seems to be the value, for which a ingress controller looks, when choosing if the ingressClass is part of his set of classes. I was able to change that value in the Helm Chart, by setting the `controller.ingressClassResource.controllerValue` to different values. In my case I chose `k8s.io/ingress-nginx/nginx` and `k8s.io/ingress-nginx/nginx-cloud` instead of the default `k8s.io/ingress-nginx`.

Comment: Solved it for me! Thanks. Does this controllerValue have any other meaning? especialy the prefix "k8s.io" to me suggests that it's defined by k8s.io? I found another site where they used k8s.io/internal-ingress-nginx.